# wxPython - Disable a whole menu

Tags: python, wxpython, wxwidgets

I have come across a problem while using wxPython lately: I want to grey out a whole wx.Menu and I can't find a way to do it. I could disable all the wx.MenuItem instances related to the wx.Menu, but I find it less efficient ergonomically speaking than greying out the menu itself.

The wx.Menu class has a method named Enable() which accepts the 'enable' argument, but its solely use is to enable/disable a related wx.MenuItem and not the wx.Menu itself. Actually, I'm not even sure that what I want can be done.

However, I would be glad to listen to your solutions if you have some.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Enable is just for the menu items. EnableTop should counter-intuitively disable the entire menu. See my old [tutorial](http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2008/07/02/wxpython-working-with-menus-toolbars-and-accelerators/) on menus about half-way down for more info. Here's how I did it:

```
self.menuBar.EnableTop(0, False)
```

Note that it's zero-based, so zero is the first menu, one is the second, etc.

Comment: Thank you very much, it works fine!
I often checked your website, but never found this tutorial. I think I should thank you even more for all the help I got from your website this month :)

By the way, I also managed to bypass the index stuff thanks to the name lookup provided by `FindMenu`.

Comment: I didn't think about the Find* methods, but that would work as long as you didn't have any items that had the same name. I'm glad you enjoy the blog. Let me know if you think of anything I should cover and I'll add it to my list of article ideas.

Comment: I don't think of anything right now, but I won't hesitate if something ever comes to my mind.

Comment: This is the sort of thing I'm looking for, but I'm finding it doesn't grey out the menu itself, it just greys out all the menu items on that menu.   Which is better than nothing, but not visually the effect I was looking for - because at the time that it's happening, the user doesn't see anything happen!  Just later they find all the menu items grey...

Comment: I just discovered that the menu is greyed out on Windows, but not on OSX.   Dang!